# Hmisc/ rcspline.eval error

Tags: r

I am getting an error while imputing my data set using Hmisc package in R studio. Can anyone tell what the error is about and how to correct it. I have don imputation same way before but never came across this.

```
validimpute <- aregImpute(~DEP_DELAY + TAXI_OUT + TAXI_IN + ARR_DELAY + CRS_ELAPSED_TIME + ACTUAL_ELAPSED_TIME + AIR_TIME + CARRIER_DELAY + WEATHER_DELAY + NAS_DELAY + SECURITY_DELAY + LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY, 
    data = validatedata, n.impute = 1)

Fewer than 3 unique knots.  Frequency table of variable:
x
     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12     13     14 
830459  13048   7361     82     30     29     33     27      9     12     22     11     13     15     10 
    15     16     17     18     19     20     21     22     23     24     25     26     27     28     29 
    17     12      8      9     16      8     11      9      5      4      6      7      1      1      5 
    30     31     32     33     34     36     39     40     41     43     44     45     46     47     49 
    13      5      7      3      4      3      9      1      2      4      9      1      2      1      4 
    51     52     54     57     58     60     63     66     72     74     77     79     80     89     91 
     1      3      1      1      1      2      4      1      4      2      4      2      4      2      1 
    93     94    107    119    121    124    127    129    132    135    141    142    143    146    150 
     1      1      1      1      1      1      2      1      4      1      1      3      1      1      1 
   162    201    207    349 
     2      1      3      1 


Error in rcspline.eval(z, knots = parms, nk = nk, inclx = TRUE) : 
In addition: Warning message:
In rcspline.eval(z, knots = parms, nk = nk, inclx = TRUE) :
  could not obtain 3 interior knots with default algorithm.
 Used alternate algorithm to obtain 3 knots
```

Answer (score 3):

set nk=0 to force linearity for non-categorical variables.
see this [link](http://127.0.0.1:25300/library/Hmisc/html/aregImpute.html) .

This also a similar [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117383/impute-missing-values-using-aregimpute) as yours asked on Cross Validated.

Hope this could help